# Poor battery life UX32VD Ubuntu 14.04 with optimus 4000/620m

Tags: 14.04, power-management, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-settings

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 ux32vd laptop and am getting only 2 hours of battery life where as on my Windows partition I get 6. I'm using a zenbook ux32vd with Intel 4000/nvidia 620m. I have the nvidia-331 / nvidia-prime 0.5 driver installed.

I tried installing `tlp` and still have terrible battery life (no noticeable improvement).

- Is there a way to check if the nvidia card is still running in the background?
- In `nvidia-settings` I have it specified to use Intel graphics, but I'm wondering what is killing the battery?

I have the lighting down to 30%. I'm running the flux 2013 script and default applications, along with chrome. Thanks!

Comment: Have you thought about accepting any answers? I think the currently most upvoted  answer should work in your hardware.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install Bumblebee to turn off the Discrete graphics card. Follow this link https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee. Also see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AsusZenbookPrime for kernel parameters to improve battery life. I am getting 5 hours with Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 came out with nvidia-prime 0.5 which supposedly allows you to switch from one GPU to another and have the discrete turned off. It seems like bumblebee is dying out, but I don't know. Thanks for your insight though.

Comment: It would be great if you do not provide link-only-answers. Please, provide summary here too.

Answer (score 1):

What is your rate of battery consumption when you look it up in the power statistics? I get around 9W of power usage when I'm using the intel graphics with the exact same laptop/ubuntu/driver versions and it leads to around 3-4 hours of battery life. I installed a little indicator to switch quickly between the intel and nvidia graphics, here it is explained how to install it: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/prime-indicator-lets-you-quickly-switch.html

Comment: 8-9. Yes same 3-4 hours. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have a lenovo u410 which also has dual graphics card. I have found that my battery life has decreased from upgrading from 13.10 to 14.04. I did have bumblebee installed on 13.10 and not on 14.04, so I think that is my problem. I don't really use the nvidia card therefore I have switched it off in the BIOS and now my battery life is back to how it was on 13.10.

I switched a setting called video from 'optimus' to 'UGA only'.

Comment: Interesting. So you find bumblebee more effective (when enabled in bios) than the nvidia driver? My bios doesn't have that option unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

I don't assume that your issue is the still running Nvidia Card (while I still believe bumblebee was more effective in switching it off compared to prime). I had a similar battery life. Then I did some optimzation by using the information from powertop to configure pm-utils.

And now I have 4:20 battery life time.

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu! Thank you for your post, however, saying you found a solution is not really answering the question.