# Is 15.10 good for Asus Zenbook UX32VD and Nvidia GPU?

Tags: nvidia, 15.10, laptop

I have an Asus Zenbook UX32VD with the following specs:

```
 -13.3" 1920x1080
 - 4 GB RAM
 - 500 GB HDD + 24 GB SSD
 - Nvidia 620M GT (1GB) + Intel HD 4000 graphics 1.9Ghz Core i7 (3517U)
```

I want to install Ubuntu on an SSD. Is it possible? Which is the best version for my computer?

Comment: Have you considered to accept any answer? Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 5):

Everything should be fine. I don't see anything special, so there should be no problem. Like others have said, your SSD is a little small, but Ubuntu can actually be configured to boot Ubuntu off of the SSD and have all your data on the 500GB drive.

Since you do have NVIDIA, I recommend installing Ubuntu 15.10. NVIDIA can be troublesome on Ubuntu, so it's usually best to have the newest version of Ubuntu. You will pretty much have to update to the next version of Ubuntu every six months, but that's an easy process. If you really don't want to upgrade every six months, and would like that frequency to be decreased to every two years, go with 14.04.

If you want to install Ubuntu on the SSD and make sure all your data is on the HDD, here's the process.

1. Download [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie) if you're on Windows and use it to burn the Ubuntu ISO you downloaded (Get 14.04 or 15.10 from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)) to a USB stick.
2. Reboot your computer and boot from the USB stick.
3. Choose the `Try Before Installing` option when prompted.
4. Search for and open `GParted`.
5. Use `GParted` to format your SSD as `ext4` (this will wipe any data on the drive so make sure your stuff is backed up).
6. Go to the dropdown in the top right and select your 500GB drive.
7. If you have any partitions on it, use the `Move/Resize` tool to make it smaller. If you can, free up at least 150GB for Ubuntu.
8. Make a new partition in that free space, formatted as `ext4`.
9. Click the `Apply` button and let the changes be made.
10. Now, open the `Install Ubuntu` app on the desktop (you can close `GParted`).
11. Click through until you are either prompted with options on how to install Ubuntu, or are met with a partition selection screen.

    - If you get the options, choose `Something Else...`
    - If you get the partition screen, continue on.
12. On the partition selection screen, right click the SSD and click `Properties`.
13. As the mountpoint, choose `/`. Also select the `Format` option and select `ext4` and the filesystem type. Click `Done.`
14. Go into Properties of the partition you created on the 500GB drive and make the mountpoint `/home`. You do not need to format this partition again.
15. Click `Continue` in the setup and Ubuntu should install.

**NOTE:** You may have a problem getting into setup, as you have NVIDIA. You might be greeted with a screen of scrolling text with the word `Nouveau` among other stuff. If this happens, follow the steps below.

1. Reboot and boot back into the USB stick.
2. On the selection screen, highlight the `Try Before Install` option, but don't hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Instead, press <kbd>e</kbd>.
3. Use your arrow keys to bring the cursor to the end of the line beginning with `linux`.
4. Press <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and type `nouveau.modeset=0`.
5. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot into setup and follow the steps above.

---

Once you have Ubuntu installed and running, you may notice that the NVIDIA card isn't being used (low performance in games/HD videos). To fix this, open the `Additional Drivers` app and select a proprietary NVIDIA driver. I recommend against using the `-updates` option(s), as these versions are experimental and not fully tested, but you're welcome to try. Instead, choose the latest non `-updates` version. Click the `Apply` button and enter your password. Reboot and you will have NVIDIA be the default card for everything.

---

**EDIT:** Another note.

If your computer came with Windows 8 or later, you may need to turn Secure Boot off. It's not probable, but possible that it will get in the way. If you want turn it off, the setting will be in your BIOS settings.

---

That should be it. Your computer should run Ubuntu without issue. If you do have a problem, come back and ask here on Ask Ubuntu (do a little research first, as your question may already have an answer).

Any questions about my answer: just comment and I'll do my best to help :-).

Answer (score 1):

My proposal

1. SSD is supported in Ubuntu 16.04/... well if it is the standard SSD provided in the Zenbook.
2. Keep Windows 10 in your system
3. Install the latest Long-term-release Ubuntu (now 16.04) as dual-boot in your system

   - the manufacturer supports firmware/... updates in Windows 10; the laptop was designed for Windows 10; Linux support is missing much
   - all Ubuntu versions will have some limitations without firmware updates; you can possibly fix/glue some of them without the updates but the updates of the manufacturer are the safest ways; however, the manufacturer says that you should not do firmware updates unless something is not working properly because it has its own risks
4. Note the NVidia GPU requires Bumblebee project's adjustments for Optimus, but may still have issues etc in power consumption/... Your integrated Intel GPU will work fine.

   - Upstream's (Debian) documentation about your NVidia GPU and hardware [here](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Asus/UX32VD) and its confirmation in Ubuntu [wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AsusZenbookPrime#Nvidia_Optimus_.28UX32VD_only.29) where only installation manual for 12.04 and 13.04, but adapt for 16.04.
   - Power consumption issues in NVidia GPU with Ubuntu [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/453758/25388),

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you plan on doing with ubuntu. 24GB is a bit small for a fully usable Ubuntu. But if you only use it for Mails or something like that, it might suffice.

According to versions: Ubuntu has two different versions. LTS-Versions like 14.04 have longer support and you don't have to worry about the ending of support in the next time. Newer Versions come with shorter support cycles until a new LTS version is released.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your configuration you can very well install Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS. But i would recommend using something light like [lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/)

Comment: Why would Lubuntu be better? Intel i7, NVIDIA and 4GB RAM are more than enough for even KDE.

Comment: @Zacharee1. It's enough but according to me this configuration is definitely low end with most of the laptops in the market coming with 16 GB RAM that's why i suggested this.

Comment: RAM really isn't a large factor in performance in Ubuntu. Sure, if you have 256MB, maybe KDE isn't for you, but 4GB is actually the norm for most home laptops nowadays. It seems low, but is fine for Windows x64. I also never see 16GB RAM as the norm. It's always 4GB for home laptops and 8GB for workstations/gaming. 16GB is what you find in the premium >$1600 laptops.

Comment: @Zacharee1. I paid less than $900 for my 15.6 HP Envy slim laptop. intel i7 Quad core processor, 16 GB of RAM, 512 GB SSD, 4GB Graphics card nvidia. Without SSD this might come in less than $800. Don't want to distract from the actual topic but i have seen some of the old laptops(my Dell which is 6 years old and have 4 GB RAM with 256 MB Graphics card and Core 2 Duo intel processor...i tried Ubuntu as well as lubuntu...lubuntu was far better as i needed some resources freed up for optimal running of the apps). Just what i discovered in my case.

Comment: I agree it's weird seeing a modern laptop with 4GB RAM, but that's the way the $300-$500 ones are. Processing speed also has something to do with it. i7 vs. C2D is a huge difference. To be fair, I tend to stay away from HP, so maybe that's why.

Comment: why i want to install Ubuntu on SSD, because they told me "if you do that, your computer will run faster" is it right?

Comment: @Ridha. SSD is considered around 10 times faster than normal hard drive. So install Ubuntu/lubuntu on SSD partition only.